# Метод заданного типа в шаблонном классе

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T>
class Class
{
    void funct() {...};
}
```

Вот надо, чтобы funct() был доступен только для определенного типа T, например int.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это делается при помощи *частичной специализации*:

```
template<typename T>
class C
{
};

template<>
class C<int>
{
    void funct() { ... }
};
```

Если хотите сделать общую часть, выделите её в базовый класс:

```
template<typename T>
class CBase
{
    void commonFunct() { ... }
};

template<typename T>
class C : public CBase<T>
{
};

template<>
class C<int> : public CBase<int>
{
    void funct() { ... }
};
```

---

Дополнение: чтобы не нужно было менять private на protected, достаточно просто объявить

```
friend class C<T>;
```

внутри `CBase`. Идею придумал самостоятельно, но до меня её озвучил уважаемый [[[[@mega](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega) в своём ответе.

---

Ещё одно дополнение: уважаемый [[[[@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg) в комментариях отметил необходимость предварительной декларации для объявления friend, так что коллективными усилиями код превращается вот в такой:

```
template<typename T>
class C;

template<typename T>
class CBase
{
private:
    int foo;
    friend class C<T>;
};

template <typename T>
class C : public CBase<T>
{
    using CBase<T>::foo;
public:
    void access() { foo = 1; } // есть везде, кроме T = int
};

template <>
class C<int> : public CBase<int>
{
    using CBase<int>::foo;
public:
    void funct() { foo = 42; } // есть только для T = int
};
```

Пример: http://ideone.com/unLF7T, http://ideone.com/BgOyxl.

Ещё раз спасибо благородным донам [[[[@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg) и [[[[@mega](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega) за приятное и плодотворное обсуждение вопроса.

Comment: а функция будет иметь к private доступ? Или сделать protected?

Comment: @iofjuupasli: Вы насчёт какой функции и каким private-данным/функциям? А вообще, как вы напишете, так и будет, действуют обычные правила.

Comment: во втором примере, как я понял, для private-полей CBase (они там есть, само собой), нужно поменять доступ на protected, чтобы funct() из C<int> имел к ним доступ. Это я уточняю.

Comment: @iofjuupasli: да, вы правы. И методов тоже, конечно.

Comment: Благодарю, @VladD, за поощрение, но право, не стоило :)

Comment: @mega: до правильного ответа мы додумались втроём, так что разделить +15 на троих справедливо.

Answer (score 4):

Тут может быть несколько стратегий

1.Описанная уважаемым [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd): выделение общего интерфейса в базовый класс. Недостатки: определенные проблемы с приватностью и пр. членов.

2.Выделение специализированной части в базовый класс:

```
template <typename T> class Base {};
template <> class Base <int> {
   void func() {...}
};

template <typename T> class Class : public Base<T> {
   // Общая часть
};
```

Недостатки: функция не может обращаться к членам производного класса.

3.Специализация самой функции

```
template <typename T> class Class {
public:
   void func();
   //Общая часть
};

template <> void Class<int>::func() {
  //нечто
}
```

---

4.Использовать фокус в стиле STATIC_ASSERT

```
template <typename T> struct _TypeSelector;
template <> struct _TypeSelector <int> {};
#define  TYPESELECTOR(type) _TypeSelector<type> _FUNC_ON_WRONG_TYPE_;

template <typename T> class Class {
public:
   void funct() {
    TYPESELECTOR (T)
    ......  
   }
};
```

Comment: Раздумываю вот, нельзя ли применить [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)...

Comment: Оказывается, можно было просто объявить friend-класс, всё просто :)

Answer (score 3):

А у меня такой вот вариант, попроще:

```
template <typename T>
class Class;

class Funct{
  friend class Class< int >;
private:
  void funct() {...};
};

template <typename T>
class Class : public Funct{
  ...
};
```

Во `friend` идет только декларация класса, поэтому он проглотит несуществующую имплементацию. А в `Class` приватный член `funct` будет доступен только для `T = int`.

Не знаю, только, что Вы будете делать с таким доступом. Чтобы использовать доступный конкретной имплементации функционал, эту имплементацию в любом случае придется специализировать **отдельно**. Так что реализация [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd)'а понадобится в любом случае.

Если только речь не о наследовании. При наследовании, к примеру: `Successor`, от `Class< T >`, если во `friend` прописать не `Class< int >`, а `Successor`, то только `Successor` будет иметь доступ к `funct`. Возможно в этом есть что-то разумное при таком ограничении доступа.

Comment: @mega: я тоже догадался насчёт friend'а, но вы написали первым. Я украду у вас эту идею, хорошо?

Вам +1.

Comment: Ничего страшного, на 4 страницы все равно редко кто спускается :)

Comment: @mega: кому реально интересен ответ, спустится.

Comment: @mega, разве можно использовать еще неопределенные имена шаблонов? gcc и icpc Вашу конструкцию отказываются кушать.

Comment: @mikillskegg: можно сделать forward-декларацию, по идее.

Comment: @VladD, насколько я помню, для шаблонов ее делать нельзя.

Comment: @mikillskegg: вроде, можно: http://ideone.com/N1bAKS

Comment: @mikillskegg: или даже так: http://ideone.com/Qf7fry

Comment: Да, действительно, проходит... Как-то встретил у Вандервуда-Джосаттиса, что нельзя. Нда...

Comment: @mikillskegg: времена меняются, и C++ меняется вместе с ними...

Comment: Ну, книга не такая уж старая. Английский оригинал вышел в 2003 г.

Comment: Спасибо, @VladD! Да, форвард шаблона тут потребуется. Добавил.